# Mysqli functions to PDO

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

i'm trying to leave mysqli and start to use PDO.

There's my function, which worked perfectly for me.

```
function get_schedule() {
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * from schedule order by schedule_id desc";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0){
        echo ("На сайте нет записей");
    }
    $row = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($result); $i++){
            $row[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
        }
    return $row;
}
```

Output of this, show all the results;
I'd changed this mysqli functions to PDO and I have some problems with output;

```
function get_schedule() {
    global $pdo;
    $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT passanger_name FROM passanger');

    if($pdo->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()')->fetchColumn()==0){
        echo ("На сайте нет записей");
    }
    $row = array();
        foreach($stmt as $row){
            $row[] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
    return $row;

}
```

Calling the function:

```
$table = get_schedule();
foreach($table as $row1){
    echo $row1['passanger_name'];
}
```

But there, when i'm calling this function, my result `A

> Notice: Undefined index: passanger_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\jollytrip.kz\test.php on line 26`

I need to fetch all the results and display it by foreach;

Comment: How are you using the output from the function in your code ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 i've edited question

Comment: what does `var_dump($table)` give you ?

Comment: Fethall в цикле примени, и почему не на русском стоке вопросс? Sorry for comment on Russian, I say what call fethAll in loop, for get result.

Comment: It looks like your function is going to return a $row variable with a single element, which then holds the remaining data. I believe you want `$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` since you're using fetchAll. Alternatively, you could do `$row[] = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` which grabs one row at a time. Check out the [fetch styles in the PDO docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Comment: @larsAnders ty dude, it works :) I've edited question, by pasting the final version, which works :)

Comment: @ATIKON You should put the solution in an answer, not edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's a final version of function

```
function get_schedule() {
global $pdo;
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT passanger_name FROM passanger');

if($pdo->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()')->fetchColumn()==0){
    echo ("На сайте нет записей");
}
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $row;

}
$table = get_schedule(); 
foreach($table as $row1){
  echo $row1['passanger_name']."<br>";
}
```